# include a php file and change the directory

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I am trying to include a chat solution in my site. 
The index file is in `root_dir` and the chat index file is in `root_dir/chat`
it workes if I include the chat index file as an iframe:

```
<iframe src="chat/index.php" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

but I am trying to pass the session's user name to the chat so I have tried this:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
chdir(CHAT_DIR);
include 'index.php';
```

I get an error. The chat solution is trying to include file from the parent directory and not the chat directory.

what can I do?

Comment: `include 'chat/index.php';` ?

Comment: tried that.. The solution was written to look in the wrong directory..

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get ? What is the value of `CHAT_DIR` ? What is the return of `chdir` ? It throws an error of level E_WARNING on failure. http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

Comment: CHAT_DIR = C:\xampp\htdocs\s-maof-vb\GoldSig\app\chat . it's the currect value. the error that i'm getting are 'Not Found - http://localhost/s-maof-vb/GoldSig/app/data/public/js/myprototype.js"'

Comment: it's looking for include files in the parent directory

Comment: From php doc site :     Note: When safe mode is enabled, PHP checks whether the directory in which the script is operating has the same UID (owner) as the script that is being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use cookies,
but you could also continue your session by linking the sites. You don't need to change the folders.

Comment: "continue your session by linking the sites" - can you expand on that?

Comment: In PHP, sessions work somehow like cookies. When you write the "session started" tag at the very beginning of a php file, the started session will go through every .php, which has that "session started" tag. So, when you are on a.php, you can offer a link to b.php and the session continues. That way, you don't have all that "includes" struggle with php-files.

Comment: are you saying that an iframe would work? because I don't understand how to include the other php file in the web page?